# call web api from JavaScript and return document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an Angular app where by I want to call my API and return a document for download. The document is stored in a MSSQL Db as an image datatype.

I've had success with the API using the following response message code

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(_document.Document);
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {Content = new StreamContent(ms)};
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-word");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", "testdocument, ".docx");
        return response;
```

This works well if calling myapi/Document in chrome, it will just download the document.

But I want to have a link in my angular app and trigger this download action.

So far I have managed to get it working by creating an "a" tag and forcing a click event using the following code

```
var a = window.document.createElement('a');

        a.href = SettingsService.getAPIURL() + "Document" + '/';
        a.download = "test";

        // Append anchor to body.
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();


        // Remove anchor from body
        document.body.removeChild(a);
```

The only problem with this is that I can't add any headers for my security tokens

The other method I have tried but not successful is the following $http request

```
 result.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            var arr = data.Document; // this is the byte[]
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);

            var a = window.document.createElement('a');

            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: data.MediaHeaderValue })); // mediaheadervalue eg "application/msword"
            a.download = "test.docx";

            // Append anchor to body.
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();

        });
```

Comment: not hard to research `ajax download` or `angular $http download`

Comment: Yes I've tried those methods but I get an error. "We're sorry. We cant open name.docx because we found a problem with its contents"

Comment: Then what you need to do is show what you tried ... and people will help sort it out. Rather than ask for people to provide solution from scratch. Problem is likely in how you are serving the document. Can't serve it as `docx` if using ajax

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard. Just open a new browser window with the URL to the document.

Comment: Yes but that would mean anyone could open the document if they knew the url, I need to secure it otherwise the way I mention in first post works fine.